# How does a window manager register itself with the X Server?

Tags: linux, xorg, window-manager

I was wondering how the window manager registers itself with the X server, and how it knows what process to kill when it goes about replacing the current window manager

Comment: The source code of `dwm` would be useful to read -- the whole window manager is just over 2000 lines, although lacking replace. Metacity's `src/core/screen.c:322` too. (I'm only suggesting as a practical example, *not* as documentation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X just keep waiting for the return of the process of wm/de. Suppose you have a line of `exec awesome` in your *~/.xinitrc*. X will start and execute that line and monitor that process return. Try putting commands below of exec line, they'll never be parsed.